# fstab entry added by GUI Disks utility seems ill-formatted but works?

Tags: fstab

The Disks utility (`gnome-disks`) added this entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[UUID] [mount pount] auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Based on numerous examples and on `info fstab`, `auto` is where the filesystem type (ext4 in this case) should be, and then `auto,`, with a comma, should start the list of options.

But the partition is mounted at startup, so `auto` is working. Is `fstab` lax about formatting? Is the Disks utility sloppy about formatting?

(Why I care: I'm about to install Ubuntu server on a new hardware system and want to add an appropriate `fstab` entry manually.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fstab-line `auto` is indeed the third field and the filesystem-type.

In the forth field which contains the mount options seperated with a comma there is no need to add the `auto`-option because it is default and this default will be used. If you don't want a partition to be automatically mounted, you'd have to use the `noauto`- option.

Here a short list of default mount-options:

```
rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async
```

You can find such information with `man mount`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not ill-formatted; the `auto` keyword may be used as both a filesystem type **and** a mount option. From `man mount`:

(as a filesystem type):

```
          If  no  -t  option  is  given, or if the auto type is specified,
          mount will try to guess the desired type.
```

(as a mount option):

```
   auto   Can be mounted with the -a option.
```